# Create a bash alias with a variable in the name without space

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Is it possible to create an alias which contains a variable in its name (i.e. *without space*)? I would like to set conversion shortcuts like hexa to binary:

For instance, when I enter:

```
0xff
```

I would like to display the following:

```
11111111
```

The idea would be something like (this example is obviously not working):

```
alias 0x$1='echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $1" | bc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in `bash`, aliases work on individual words. So, unless you want to do:

```
alias 0x00='echo 00000000'
alias 0x01='echo 00000001'
```

then you're not going to get it working easily. It *can* be done (for a limited range) using that method by creating a script to source on the fly but it will result in a lot of aliases:

```
( for i in {0..255} ; do printf "alias 0x%02x='echo %d'\n" $i $i ; done ) >xyzzy_$$.sh
source xyzzy_$$.sh
rm xyzzy_$$.sh
```

---

Instead, I'd just opt for an function `x` where you could do:

```
pax> x ff
11111111
```

There are no more keystrokes than you would need for `0xff` and you don't have to worry about trying to coerce `bash` into doing something it's not really built to do.

Such a function can be created with:

```
pax> x() {
...>    val=$(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <<< $1)
...>    BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<< "ibase=16;obase=2;$val"
...> }
```

and used as follows:

```
pax> x ff
11111111

pax> x 42
1000010

pax> x cB
11001011

pax> x 457365384563453653276537456354635635326535635345
10001010111001101100101001110000100010101100011010001010011011001010011001001110110010100110111010001010110001101010100011000110101011000110101001100100110010100110101011000110101001101000101
```

Note the use of `tr` to coerce alphas into uppercase values. Without that, you're likely to run into problems with `bc` recognising them as valid hex digits.

Also note the setting of `BC_LINE_LENGTH` to prevent `bc` from auto-wrapping very large numbers, such as that last one where you would otherwise see:

```
pax> y 457365384563453653276537456354635635326535635345
10001010111001101100101001110000100010101100011010001010011011001010\
01100100111011001010011011101000101011000110101010001100011010101100\
0110101001100100110010100110101011000110101001101000101
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` aliases does not take variables as input(s). You can use a function instead:

```
$ hex_to_bin () { echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $1" | bc ;}

$ hex_to_bin 6A
1101010
```